# Completely stuck on loading JQuery into a WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

this may seem like a simple error but I've been stuck on it.

I am running a WordPress installation with a script that I found which hides the header based on scroll. They script worked perfectly while on the page itself enclosed in  tags until I started loading it into the WordPress theme with a separate file.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'greycanary-effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/effects.js', array(), '20120206', true );
```

And the script...

```
( function() {
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = $('.main-navigation').outerHeight();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;

        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $('.main-navigation').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('.main-navigation').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    };
});
```

Comment: is there a script error?

Comment: You may want to check where Wordpress is loading it - it could be different to where you were loading it before.

Comment: WordPress is loading it into almost the same area of the page as it was before. It is in the page footer.

Comment: Here is the link to the test site.

http://michaelwood.ca/digital-marketing/

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to replace all of your $ references to either be "jQuery"; or you'll need to create a variable named "$":

e.g. put this at the top of your function(){

```
(function(){
    $ = jQuery;
    ....
```

OR

```
( function() {
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = jQuery('.main-navigation').outerHeight();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;

        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            jQuery('.main-navigation').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + jQuery(window).height() < jQuery(document).height()) {
                jQuery('.main-navigation').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    };
});
```

Comment: I've changed the code but still have no success. It's currently up as the second option.

Answer (score 1):

In the wordpress jquery you cannot use the $ sign they use this to prevent conflicting javascript. Use jQuery instead.
I see you did use jQuery but on some lines you used the dollar sign

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to do this instead:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'greycanary-effects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/effects.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20120206', true );
```

The `array( 'jquery' )` tells wordpress that your script depends on jquery and should be loaded after it.

See [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more info on how to enqueue scripts with depenencies

Also if your'e going to use `$` you should do it like this

```
( function( $ ) {
    // Use $ here instead of jQuery if you want
    ...
} )( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it,

It was an issue with switching out the $ to jQuery. It is used throughout the script and needed to be changed on all of them.